# Rare audio issue

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I use UbuntuStudio 16.04.4 LTS, into two identical MSI Computers (both with MS-7788 Motherboard and Intel I5 processors).

Both have the same Intel generic sound card (included into the main motherboard).

Well, the rare issue is... Into one of them I can get full 5.1 surround sound, but... Into the other I just get Stereo sound.

Both have and use the same software.

At both devices I edited the **/etc/pulse/daemon.conf** file with the line:

**; default-sample-channels = 6**

But, When I open the pavucontrol... In the "problematic" computer I just have "Stereo Duplex Output" as the option to the sound output mode (in the other PC I can get the surround output).

What's wrong here??

How can I fix it???

Comment: I would suggest that you check that there is no file with different configuration in ~/.pulse and post a pulse audio log as described in https://askubuntu.com/tags/sound/info

Comment: I notice the line you edited STILL HAS A SEMI-COLON, which means it is "commented out" or ignored, was that intentional?

Comment: It seems to me that it is intentional. But... I'm not a programmer so... I'm not the person to get a good answer for that.

Comment: BTW: I reinstall all PulseAudio and Alsa packages (with Synaptic) and now... All is work so fine!!! I guess something was missed. How can I say that this problem was solved???